# Script to read from 2 x files and print only what is not common

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to compare 2 x files. If the contents are not commons, I want to echo them.

Here is my code thus far

```
#!/bin/bash


while IFS= read -r line && IFS= read -r line2 <&3; do
  
 if [ "$line" -ne "$line2" ]; then
    echo "we  doing this $line2"
    
  else
    echo "we will not  do this $line2"
  fi

done <file1test 3<file2test
```

The contents of each file which I am testing are just numbers. file1test is from 1..10 per line  and file2test if from 1..20 per line.

My code only echos 1..10 which is common to both.

Comment: Read `man comm`.

Comment: Why trying to re-invert the wheel when "diff" and "comm" commands are readily available?

Comment: If you're asking *why* it only "echos 1..10" then remember `IFS= read -r line && IFS= read -r line2 <&3` is only true if **both** `read`s succeed

Comment: @steeldriver - thanks for picking that up.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working, with the use of a status flag

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
   
 
  status=0
  while IFS= read -r line2 <&3
  do

  if [ "$line" = "$line2" ]; then
     status=1
     break 
  fi
 
done 3< file1test
if [ "$status" != 1 ]; then
  echo "$line"
fi
done < file2test
```